# Facebook like button causing page to jump when loading

Tags: html, css, facebook-like

I have tried implementing the facebook like button on my website but it causes the content that comes after  to jump when loading. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
<div class="breadcrumb clearfix">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="{{ shop.url }}" title="{{ shop.name | escape }}" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">Home</span></a></span> 
    <span class="arrow-space">&#62;</span>
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="{{ collection.url }}" title="{{ collection.title | escape }}" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">{{ collection.title }}</span></a></span>       

    {% if current_tags %}
      {% for tag in current_tags %}
        <span class="arrow-space">&#62;</span>
        <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="/collections/{% if collection.handle != blank %}{{ collection.handle }}{% else %}all{% endif %}/{{ tag | handleize }}" title="{{ tag | escape }}" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title">{{ tag }}</span></a></span>       
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if paginate.pages != 0 %}      
      <span class="arrow-space">&#62;</span> <strong>Page {{ paginate.current_page }} of {{ paginate.pages }}</strong>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="hide-fb">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/festrags" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true" data-width="0px">
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

And here is the css (hopefully I have picked out the relevant part..)

```
.clearfix:after, .row:after { clear:both; }
.clearfix, .row { zoom:1; }

.breadcrumb { font-size: 12px; margin: 0 0 30px 0; }
.breadcrumb .arrow-space { margin: -2px 6px 0; font-size: 10px; opacity: .5; filter:alpha(opacity=50); }
.breadcrumb a { color: {{ settings.body_font_color }}; }
```

If you look at the home page http://festrags.com/ (password="cheaye")
The button doesn't cause a jump but on the product and collection pages it does http://festrags.com/collections/all

I have tried adding a width and height but it is just cutting off the frame and when I make it big enough it just pushes the content down.

Comment: Sorry, i can not Test With developer tools atm. If you give the same height to the parent container of the iframe and your breadcrumb items, the Space for the like button should be "reserved" even if the Button has Not been loaded yet. Is the `.hide-fb` Container appended by javascript? If that is the Case, that would explain the "jump". The wrapping Container should be loaded with the default Template. If i'am wrong, i will get back to you tomorrow, when i'am back at the desktop

Comment: If you add 
`.breadcrumb .hide-fb
{
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
}`
The jumping in the list view should stop.

Answer (score 1):

The like Button is loading an iframe to your page, which is too Large for the desired viewport. Try to add this:

```
.hide-fb
{
    Overflow:hidden;
}
```

If that should Not work like that. You will have to add a certain width and height also.

To prevent the content of your list view to jump, you can add this css:

```
.breadcrumb .hide-fb { 
    height: 34px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

The FB container has a height of 34px max (in this case), so when it's loaded your container (.hide-fb) will already have the correct height.

Update: Since the implemention above is cutting off the fb Share modal, we just Need to prevent the overflow until the iframe is loaded completly.

Try to remove every implementation of .hide-fb, that contains overflow:hidden; then just add this to your css:

```
.hide-fb:empty { 
    height: 34px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

The Containers from the fb like plugin should Not be Cut off

Update 3:
This is beginning to get silly...
I've created a fiddle of your page and all I did was this:

```
.hide-fb {
    height: 34px;
}
```

your `float: right` is also applyed to that element. Now when i load the page the element is not jumping, when FB is loaded. Also I can use all controls without having them cut off. It Could be the german Facebook behaves differently or uses different controls. But the Share Window is opened in a new browser popup. When you click "like" a dialog appears that says: "Say more about this..." this look like it could have been cut off, but it is not. It seems to have to look like that.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll need to add a width & height.

Comment: I have added some comments to my question. Still not getting it working correctly.

Comment: The problems is that once this is implemented then when the like button is clicked it doesn't display the iframe properly...please see it live on my site now.

Comment: I see. Ok, we can go a bit Hacky. Try to have the .hide-fb container completly empty, no white space, no new line `<div class="hide-fb"></div>` then alter the css for the overflow, to this: `.hide-fb:empty {overflow:hidden;}` Worth a try.

Comment: Hmm its not working (I've left my site with your implementation so you can see it. Plus I was using the <div class="hide-fb"> to float the button right.

Comment: Please See the edit of the anwer. Like yesterday i will Look at it with tools tomorrow if the Problems persists

Comment: OK thanks for the help. `.breadcrumb .hide-fb { height: 34px; overflow: hidden; }` works but cuts off the frame once the button is clicked.....`hide-fb:empty { height: 34px; overflow: hidden; } ` causes the jump to still occur.

Comment: Oh man i'am sorry to have you debugging like that.   Last try for tonight: `.hide-fb { height:34px; } .hide-fb:empty { overflow:hidden; } ` i will answer with tested definition tomorrow

Comment: There Must be a Simple Way... What Happen when you remove the .hide-fb overflow and height and do this? `.hide-fb iframe { max-height:34px; }` .... I should stop guessing ;)

Comment: Any more luck with this Nico?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The solution was to force the button to be of particular dimensions, rather than unstyled:

```
.fb-like {
    height: 30px;
    width: 78px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But this would mean that the "Like" popup could not appear. My subsequent solution was to add a new class `fb-like-not-fixed-yet`, which would have the fixes above - and set a `window.setTimeout` to remove the class once the Like button had loaded. Yuck.